# Generate table in XSL from XML

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, polarion

i want to make an XSL file to generate PDF`s with it.

```html
         <values>
            <item>
              <html>
                <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Step</p>
              </html>
            </item>
            <item>
              <html>
                <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Description</p>
              </html>
            </item>
            <item>
              <html>
                <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Result</p>
              </html>
            </item>
          </values>
```

No i want to represent this my PDF as Table, but i dont get how to implement it in my existing file.

[The Result should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdw8S.png)

Im really new in XSL and i hope some can help to solve this problem.

Many greetings

Comment: So what is the problem, the FO markup to create a table? See http://w3schools.sinsixx.com/xslfo/xslfo_tables.asp.htm for a simple example or consult the W3C FO spec for details. Or simply generating such a table structure from your XML snippet with XSLT? It should be easy to map each `item` element to a FO table cell containing the text from the `p` element.

Comment: The problem is to create a table from my XML with XSLT. I am always getting some errors or an empty table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minimal sample to transform that XML snippet into an XSL-FO table is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fo xhtml"
    version="3.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="sample">
                <fo:region-body/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="sample">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="values">
    <fo:table>
        <fo:table-column column-width="*"/>
        <fo:table-column column-width="*"/>
        <fo:table-column column-width="*"/>
        <fo:table-header>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:block font-weight="bold">Step</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:block font-weight="bold">Step description</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:block font-weight="bold">Expected result</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-header>

        <fo:table-body>
          <fo:table-row>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
   <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block>
          <xsl:value-of select="html/xhtml:p"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJ4 that transforms your input snippet into the FO

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="sample">
         <fo:region-body/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="sample">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:block>
            <fo:table>
               <fo:table-column column-width="*"/>
               <fo:table-column column-width="*"/>
               <fo:table-column column-width="*"/>
               <fo:table-header>
                  <fo:table-row>
                     <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block font-weight="bold">Step</fo:block>
                     </fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block font-weight="bold">Step description</fo:block>
                     </fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block font-weight="bold">Expected result</fo:block>
                     </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
               </fo:table-header>
               <fo:table-body>
                  <fo:table-row>
                     <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block> i am a step</fo:block>
                     </fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>i am a desc</fo:block>
                     </fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>i am a res</fo:block>
                     </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
               </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
         </fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

which renders as a table, you will need to add attributes to have borders.

To insert that approach into your existing stylesheet, you will to take the input namespace into account and prefix the match expressions or select expressions as you have done in the other parts of the stylesheet and then you only need to insert the last two templates into your stylesheet and make sure that you use `<xsl:apply-templates/>` or `<xsl:apply-templates select="values"/>` (again, with any needed namespace prefix) at the place where you want to insert the table in the context of the parent of the `values` element.

Comment: i tried it until now, and im unable to match the tables with my xml File. But thx for your help mate

Comment: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rM6 is an example to integrate the above snippet into the complete stylesheet you linked to, I am sure the position of the table is not where you want but hopefully with that example you can adjust the code to integrate the table where needed.

Comment: thx a lot! Im trying now to change the place of the table. But when i call the tamplate in a nother match, i dont get it. Now in your example its under the chapter "Requirements", but i need the table under "Test Cases". Can u give me another Note pls to understand it.

Comment: See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rM6/2 where I put the `apply-templates` in a different location, I had to use an absolute path to be able to select the elements from that context.

Comment: Thats right, now its in the right location, but still in the other one. Can i make a if statement where i ask (if name == Test Case) then only apply the template?